# How can i post react and ajax data to rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, reactjs

I am developing an application with reactjs on frontend and rails on backend. I am new to rails . I have developed a registration system using reactjs and now i want to post the data to the server. I am not using react-rails gems for this. I dont know what to do next for posting data to server. Could anyone please enlighten me? What should i do now ? Is there anything that i have to provide? 
P.S I am not using react-rails gem.

**My React Code for registration of room (shortened by removing description and some other fields)**

```
var fieldValues = {
  ownerName:'',
  email:'',
  phoneNumber:'',
  image:[]

}


class AddRent extends React.Component{
 constructor(props,context) {
        super(props,context);
        this.state = {
            step: 1
        };
    }

  saveValues(field_value) {
    return function() {
      fieldValues = Object.assign({}, fieldValues, field_value)
    }()
    console.log('fieldValues are', fieldValues);
  }


  nextStep(step) {
    var step = this.state.step;
    var newStep = step+1;
    this.setState({step:newStep});
  }

  previousStep(step) {
    var step = this.state.step;
    var newStep = step-1
    this.setState({
      step : newStep
    });
  }


  showStep() {
  switch (this.state.step) {
    case 1:
      return <RenderPersonalInfo fieldValues={fieldValues}
                            nextStep={this.nextStep.bind(this)}
                            previousStep={this.previousStep.bind(this)}
                            saveValues={this.saveValues.bind(this)} />
    case 6:
      return <RenderPhotos fieldValues={fieldValues}
                           nextStep={this.nextStep.bind(this)}
                           previousStep={this.previousStep.bind(this)} />
  }
}

  render() {
    var style = {
      width : (this.state.step / 6 * 100) + '%'
    }

    return (
      <main>
        <span className="progress-step">Step {this.state.step}</span>
        <progress className="progress" style={style}></progress>
        {this.showStep()}
      </main>
    )
  }
};

class RenderPersonalInfo extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
            <div>
              <h3>Personal Information</h3>
              <p className="subtitle">Provide your authentic information so rent seekers can contact you</p>
              <hr/>
              <div className="col-md-4">
                <label htmlFor='name'>Owner Name</label>
                <input ref="name" defaultValue={this.props.fieldValues.ownerName} type="textbox" className="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Owner name" />
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-4">
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <input ref="email" defaultValue={this.props.fieldValues.email} type="email" className="form-control" id="email" placeholder="email" />
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-4">
                <label htmlFor="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                <input ref="phone" defaultValue={this.props.fieldValues.phoneNumber} type="textbox" className="form-control" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="phone number" />
              </div>
              <hr/>
                <div className="row continueBtn text-right">
                    <button className="btn how-it-works" ref="personalInfo" onClick={this.nextStep.bind(this)}>Continue</button>
                </div>
            </div>
      );
  }
  nextStep(step){
     var data = {
          ownerName  : this.refs.name.value,
          email : this.refs.email.value,
          phoneNumber: this.refs.phone.value,
        }
        console.log(data.ownerName);
        if ((data.ownerName)&&(data.email)&&(data.phoneNumber)) {
          this.props.saveValues(data);
          this.props.nextStep();
        }
        else{
          alert('please enter the name, email and phone number');
        }
  }
};

 class RenderPhotos extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            files: []
        };
    }

    onDrop(files) {
      console.log('Received files: ', files);
      this.setState({
          files: files
      });

      var image = [];
      image = new FormData(files);
      $.each(files,function(i,file){
        image.append('image',file);
      });
     $.ajax({
      url:"",
      data:image,
      contentType:false,
      processData:false,
      type:'POST',
      mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('success');
      }
     });
  }

    showFiles() {
        const { files } = this.state;
        console.log('files',files);

        if (!files.length) {
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Dropped files: </h3>
                <ul className="gallery">
                    {
                        files.map((file, idx) => {
                            return (
                                <li className="col-md-3" key={idx}>
                                    <img src={file.preview} width={200}/>
                                    <div>{file.name}</div>
                                </li>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
      return (
           <div>
                <p>Add photos of spaces to give more insight of your space </p>
                <hr/>
                <div className="col-md-12">
                <form method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data">
                  <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop.bind(this)}>
                    Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.
                </Dropzone>
              </form>
                {this.showFiles()}
              </div>
              <div className="row continueBtn text-right">
                    <button className="btn how-it-works pull-left" onClick={this.props.previousStep.bind(this)}>Back</button>
                    <button className="btn how-it-works" onClick={this.nextStep.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
               </div>
            </div>

      );
    }

       nextStep(step){
                  var sendData={'ownerName':this.props.fieldValues.ownerName,
                        'email':this.props.fieldValues.email,
                        'phoneNumber':this.props.fieldValues.phoneNumber,
                      }
                  console.log(sendData.email);
                  $.ajax({
                  url:"",
                  data:sendData,
                  type:'POST',
                  success: function(data) {
                    console.log('success');
                  }
                 });
       }


}

export default AddRent;
```

**My rooms_controller**

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @rooms = Room.all
    end

    def new
      @room = Room.new
    end

    def create
      @room = Room.new(listing_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        if @room.save
          format.html { redirect_to @room, notice: 'Room was successfully listed.' }
          format.json { render json: @room }
      else
        format.html {render :new}
        format.html {render json:@room.errors}
      end
    end

    private

    def listing_params
      params.require(:room).permit(:ownerName, :email, :phoneNumber, :listingName, :summary, :property, :room, :price, :city, :place, :water, :amenities, :is_published)
    end
end
```

**Models for room(migration file)**

```
class CreateRooms < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :rooms do |t|
      t.string :ownerName
      t.string :email
      t.integer :phoneNumber
      t.string :listingName
      t.text :summary
      t.string :property
      t.integer :room
      t.integer :price
      t.string :city
      t.string :place
      t.string :water
      t.string :amenities
      t.boolean :is_published

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Where's the problem exactly?  You have ajax calls included, which seems reasonable (though the url's are empty?).  Without knowing what errors you're getting, or what stage you're stuck at, it's hard to give insight.

Comment: I have no idea . i think i should pass the url that maps to create action in controller and create a create.js.erb but i am not sure. Is that what i have to do ? I am wanting for the idea as i have not seen anything such in internet except  through react-rails gem. I want to know what should i do next after creating a form entirely on reactjs.

Comment: This isn't really a react or a rails issue, it's an ajax/api issue.  Look into how to build and access an API endpoint in rails, which receives and provides JSON rather than rendering a view (no .erb files for this).  You don't even really need any gems for this, just an understanding of how an API/ajax functions.  Rails' `render json:` option is also going to be useful, but you really should do a small bit of research first before diving in if you've never used/created an API before.

Comment: This is my first time with rails . I have successfully developed similar function on django but i want to taste ruby on rails too. Thanks for your idea. I will look at rails api . Again thanks for your valuable help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the `csrf` token in the ajax headers or you need to disable csrf protection